# Search SQL by date ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

My code:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
con.ConnectionString = "provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0; data source=D:/c# database/Database3.mdb";
con.Open();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From TEST WHERE MatchDate >= '"+ date.ToString() +"'", con);
da.Fill(ds);
Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
Repeater1.DataBind();
con.Close();
```

Could You tell me, why this code won't work ?. Program is throwing an exception. I'am using MS Access database. Date format in databese looks like this date: "2014-06-27 18:45:00"

Comment: And the exception is ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that. I'am using polish version of "Visual web developer", in english that exception should be like "Data type mismatch in criteria expression". I hope so, You will know what that mean..

Comment: As an aside (since using a parameterized query is the way to go) you don't delimit dates with quotes in Access it's `#`. Which explains the mistmatch (date vs a string) This really only comes into play if you need to hardcode a date in your string e.g. `where somedate < #2008-07-31#`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should parameterized your query. `DateTime` doesn't have any format associated with it, Format is only useful for displaying purpose.

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * From TEST WHERE MatchDate >= @matchDate", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@matchDate", DateTime.Today); // Just date part comparision
                                                           // Or use DateTime.Now depending on your requirement)

OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(ds);
```

This will save you from [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) as well, and it will take care of the `DateTime` value.

Also instead of `DateTime.Now` it appears that you want to compare records greater than particular date, instead of Date and Time, Use `DateTime.Today` or `DateTime.Now.Date`. This will have Time part set to `00:00` so you can compare records against a particular Date.

You should also enclose your Command/Connection objects with [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement, since they implement `IDisposable` interface and will ensure connection disposal even in case of exception.